# ValueError when training Autoencoder in Keras for unsupervised learning

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, autoencoder, unsupervised-learning

I'm trying to use an autoencoder within Keras to do unsupervised classification of hyperspectral images using the Indian Pines dataset. I had started with a Project here https://github.com/KonstantinosF/Classification-of-Hyperspectral-Image and have modified the section in [TrainTheModel.ipynb](https://github.com/KonstantinosF/Classification-of-Hyperspectral-Image/blob/master/TrainTheModel.ipynb), replacing **"Train the model"** section (and the following two code blocks) with the following code, which is just the encoding side of the autoencoder:

```python
input_img = Input(shape=input_shape)  # input_shape is (30, 5, 5)
x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img) # x1
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x) # x2
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x) # x3
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x) # x4
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x) #x5
encoded = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)

model = Model(input_img, encoded)
model.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')

model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=15)
```

which I adapted from the **"Convolutional Autoencoder"** section of https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html.  When I try to run the command:

```python
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=15)
```

command, I get the error message:

```python
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected max_pooling2d_25 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (29685, 16)
```

Since I'm a new to CNN, I'm uncertain why my dimensions are not coming out correct. If I print out the shape of each step here I get:

```python
(?, 16, 5, 5) # x1
(?, 16, 3, 3) # x2
(?, 8, 3, 3) # x3
(?, 8, 2, 2) # x4
(?, 8, 2, 2) # x5
(?, 8, 1, 1) # encoded
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

From your error i assume that your network expects data of shape input_shape=(num,x,z,z) but instead it is fed with data of shape (29685, 16).

Check your X_train, y_train shape

(also be careful with your `image_data_format` whether it would be `channels_last` or `channels_first`